# Display tags in article based on language?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

This is my relationship:

article:

```
  public function tags(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\ATags', 'article_tags','article_id', 'article_tag_id');
    }
```

language:

```
  public function tags(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\ATags', 'language_id');
    }
```

Here i get all tags for specific language. I want now to display all tags for that language for that specific article.

```
foreach($languages as $language){
        $tags[] = $language->tags;
      }
```

Any suggestion how can i do that?

I tried this but i get an error

```
$tags1 = $tags->whereHas('articles', function ($query) {
        $query->where('id', '=', $article_id);
      })->get();
```

I have two languages, and what im trying to get is to have tags for that two languages.

This is my controller:

```
 public function edit($article_id){


      $user = $this->user;
      $languages = $this->languages;
      $article = Articles::findOrFail($article_id);
      $article_trans = $article->translations;
      foreach($languages as $language){
        $tags = $language->tags;
      }

      $tags1 = $tags->whereHas('articles', function ($query) {
        $query->where('id', '=', $article_id);
      })->get();
    }
```

This is view for tags:

```
  <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="form-group">
       <label class="form_title">ARTICLE TAGS</label>

 <input type="text" name="tags[{{$article_tran->language->code }}]" class="form-control tokenfield" value="{{ $user_tags }}" />
 </div>
```

Comment: Can you describe a little more what do you mean by "based on language"? What do you expect to get as a result and what have you tried so far?

Comment: Where's the code of Controller that return the data?

Comment: normal submission, and why is that  important am i using laravel login/registration?

Comment: If normal submission, why there's no Request parameters on edit? You need to give us the form VIEW also.

Comment: Im trying to display tags here in view first, after that i will do request

Comment: I asked you about the login/registration because I saw the code `$this->user;` and I think If you are using laravel auth. You can take advantage of what laravel Auth gives you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems your closer is not getting the value of article_id assuming your ATag model has relation belongsToMany defined as articles.

```
public function edit($article_id){

      $user = $this->user;
      $languages = $this->languages;
      $article = Articles::findOrFail($article_id);
      $article_trans = $article->translations;
      $tags = [];
      foreach($languages as $language){
        //because of loop take array of tags
        $tags[] = $language->tags()->whereHas('articles', function($query) use($article_id){
             $query->where('id', '=', $article_id);
        })->get();
      }
 }
```

consider the use($article_id) in whereHas closure and whereHas doesn't work with collection when you call $language->tags which returns the collection not builder
also have you defined the articles relation properly in ATag model?